# If $F$ is a $1$-to-$1$ imersion and is proper then $F$ is an imbedding

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

> Let $F:N\rightarrow M$ be a one-to-one immersion which is proper, i.e. the inverse image of any compact set is compact. Show that $F$ is an imbedding and that its image is a closed regular submanifold of $M$ and conversely.

This is an exercise from Bothby: an introduction to diferentiable manifolds. Pag. 81, ex. 6

the following theorem say something very similar on what the exercise asks

if $F:N\rightarrow M$ is an one-to-one immersion and $N$ is compact, the $F$ is and imbedding and $F(N)$ is a regular submanifold. Thus a submanifold of $M$, if compact in $M$, is regular.

Well, this theorem states exactaly what i want to show, but my dificulty is how changing the hypothesis of $N$ being compact for $F$ being proper could take me to the desired result?

Comment: forget about the theorem. Can you tell what you have tried with the exercise? What would be your first step?

Comment: well, this seems to be a purely topological result, since manifolds are locally euclidean spaces i would prove that $F$ beeing proper implies that it is a closed map. Thats all, i have no ideia now how to prove that the image of $F$ is closed

Comment: How does proving proper implies closed map help in this situation.?

Comment: well, that would implies $F$ it`s a imbedding, because its inverse would be continous, right?

Comment: Can you write down completely your approach. I don’t want to guess that you know something when you don’t say that.. please say clearly how do you go from hypothesis to result assuming f is closed map..

Answer (score 1):

Assume that it is not an embedding. For $p\in f(N)$, consider $$ f(N)\ \bigcap\ B\bigg(p,\frac{1}{n}\bigg)
 \supseteq U\cup \{p_n\}$$ where $U$ is homeomorphic to
 ${\rm dim}\ N$-dimensional open ball.

Hence $p_n\rightarrow p$ so that $\{p_1,\cdots \}\cup B(p,\varepsilon) $ is compact. Its preimage contains
  $U'$ and infinite points $p_n'\in f^{-1}(p_n)$ where $U'$ is homeomorphic to a ${\rm dim}\ N$-dimensional open ball.

By proper, $p_n'$ converges to $q$ which is not in $U'$. Then
$f(p_n')\rightarrow f(q)\neq p$. It is a contradiction.

Comment: sorry, but that inclusion is to fast for me to get, $U$ is where i defined a chart of $M$?

Comment: $U$ is a chart for $f(N)$ where $f$ is an immersion.